# difference when using dot syntax with ClassName or self

Tags: python

When accessing class attributes, what is the difference when using the class name `Foo` or `self` within that classes methods?

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     class_attribute = "Oh Hai"
...     def bar(self):
...         print(Foo.class_attribute)
...         print(self.class_attribute)
...
>>> Foo().bar()
Oh Hai
Oh Hai
```

Both work. In both cases I assume Python looks at the instance of the class and doesn't find the class attributes bound to it so then it proceeds to check the class attributes and find `class_attribute`.

Is one more efficient than the other?

Is it just a personal preference for code readability? To me seeing `ClassName.class_attribute` used *within* that class looks odd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: That one covers capability, this one covers reasoning. Not a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Baz(Foo):
  class_attribute = "Hello, World!"

Baz().bar()
```

And now they have completely different behavior. Program for results, not for efficiency.

Comment: So there's only a difference when inheriting? If not inheriting (considering Foo class in isolation), is there any difference other than personal preference / code readability?  Good example btw, implications for inheritance had not occurred to me.